# Improve slow Java code efficiency

Tags: java, android, performance

The following code is taking ~ 550ms to run and the user is waiting for this to happen constantly (besides some extra processing from an external library). Is there a way to improve this transformation from  an array of int (pixels) to the final Bitmap?

```
int[] pixels   = imageDecoder.nativeGetImgBytes();  // a big tiff image

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);

byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();
b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, array.length);

return b;
```

Comment: 550ms doesn't sound long, but combined with "the user is waiting for this to happen constantly" leads to the question "What are you actually trying to do"? Perhaps you don't need to be doing all of this as often as you are...

Comment: What is all this stuff for? What point is there in converting the newly-created `Bitmap` into a byte array, then back again? Why not just return `Bitmap.createBitmap(...)` and be done with it?

Comment: The pixels array is coming from a C++ library. It's the result of processing a raw Nikon photo converted to TIFF. After that I'm taking the pixels int[] array and creating a jpeg compressed Bitmap that's finally obtainer and displayed in the screen by other class.

Comment: Please elaborate on "the user is waiting for this to happen constantly", but in any case, make sure this bitmap calculation is taking place within an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) so that the UI does not hang on the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After that I'm taking the pixels int[] array and creating a jpeg compressed Bitmap that's finally obtainer and displayed in the screen by other class.

No, you are not. A `Bitmap` is not compressed. A bitmap file may be compressed, but a `Bitmap` is not.

So, replace your code with:

```
int[] pixels   = imageDecoder.nativeGetImgBytes();  // a big tiff image

return Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Beyond the wasted CPU time of encoding and decoding the JPEG, your existing code is wasting a lot of heap space. You wind up with two complete `Bitmap` instances and many heap allocations as the `ByteArrayOutputStream` slowly expands from its initial size to whatever its final size is.

Comment: btw compress method does not compress bitmap ?

Comment: Yes, `compress` compresses the bitmap.  But then `decodeByteArray` decompresses it again.  What the OP is doing is pointless at best, and probably degrades the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot CommonsWare, you were right and I see what you mean now. I was sure that code was suspicious :) It's now taking only 80ms!